# How to use 301 redirect in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, http-status-code-301

I want use 301 redirect in my website. I try to redirect "http://localhost:54996/AboutUs.aspx" to "http://localhost:54996/About". 
I use this code in my page load:

```
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://localhost:54996/About");
```

or this code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.FilePath == "/AboutUs.aspx")
    {
         Response.RedirectPermanent("/About", true);
    }
}
```

But none of these solutions work. When i enter my address(http://localhost:54996/AboutUs.aspx), i go to this address: "about/"

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A redirect 301 or 302 is the correct response code, web crawlers use it to tell if pages have moved location either temporarily or permanently.

I think what you want is **url rewrites**, not *redirects*.

A great way is doing all the redirects in IIS, early on in the pipeline before it hits the `Application_BeginRequest` event:
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

With the code the specified URL has to be a absolute URL else it will try to redirect to within your application.

`Response.RedirectPermanent(<URL> + "/About..`